# Protect the password when using Mysql in an unattended bash-script

Tags: mysql, bash, security, password-protection

I am writing a bash script (for a cron job) that uses mysql:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e 'something;'
```

I am looking for a good way to keep the password handy for use in the script, but in a manner that will also keep this information secure from other users on that system. Users who could use ps -ef and users who might read text files...

So how can I safeguard passwords that will be used in an automated script on Linux?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put all the settings in an option file. You can use your default `~/.my.cnf` file, or you can specify an alternate file using `--defaults-file==filename`. See the documentation [4.2.3.4. Command-Line Options that Affect Option-File Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html)

The option file contains default settings for mysql commands. You can put the following in it, for example.

```
[mysql]
user=username
password=password
database=yourdb
```

Make the option file readable only by you, so other users can't see your password.

Comment: Yes i read that answer before - but i don't understand - what is an option file?

Comment: See the example in the answer.

Comment: Better Question: How does storing it in this "option file" differ from just storing it in an txt file just readable for me?

Comment: Since you can store multiple options in the file, it's simpler since you don't have to write all the scripting to set several different shell variables from the file.

Comment: Found my answer after some googling now - mysql reads the login from this file by default and if I write it in this file I don't need username and password to log in to mysql - so I don't have to read password and username from this .my.conf file for my script but can just use mysql without an login. Why didn't you just say?

Comment: I thought I said that. And I gave a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

**This is an updated answer for users of MySQL 5.6.6+**

As documented in [4.6.6 mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html), there is now a more secure way to store mySQL passwords, that does not store clear text passwords in a local configuration file.

> The mysql_config_editor utility (available as of MySQL 5.6.6) enables
>   you to store authentication credentials in an **encrypted** login path
>   file named .mylogin.cnf. The file location is the %APPDATA%\MySQL
>   directory on Windows and the current user's home directory on
>   non-Windows systems. The file can be read later by MySQL client
>   programs to obtain authentication credentials for connecting to MySQL
>   Server.

This file can be created by running the following command:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=client  --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

You can print the existing settings with the following command:

```
mysql_config_editor print --login-path=client
```

This will output the current settings:

```
[client]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost
```

Notice the password is encrypted by default.

Answer (score 4):

create a file `~/.my.cnf` in the home directory of the user running the cron job. make sure is not readable by other users ( `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf` )

```
[client]
user=username
password=something
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - as they are the same answers this is also helpful but i can't mark both. :-)